# TypeError: Cannot read property '49' of undefined; for MachineTyping effect component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem with this component. I've tried to convert it from Vanilla JavaScript one, which works perfectly. But that one not so much. I know there is something wrong with my usage of setState() method so many times, but I can't figure it out, what exactly. Can someone help me to make it to fully work?

```
class AnimationTypingText extends Component {
    state = {
        text: '',
        indexText: 0,
        activeLetter: 0,
        activeText: 0,
    }

    idInterval = setInterval(() => this.addLetter(), 50);

    addLetter = () => {

        const txt = [
            'HTML Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur',
            'CSS adipisicing elit. Repellat, laudantium dolorum',
            'JavaScript consequuntur dicta esse soluta aut assumenda', 
            'React error iusto qui atque necessitatibus ', 
            'Node tempore dolor laborum.', 
            'MongoDB Aspernatur quam voluptatum quis possimus.'];     

        if ( this.state.activeLetter >= 0 ) {
            this.setState({
                text: this.state.text + txt[this.state.activeText][this.state.activeLetter],
            });
        }
        this.setState({
            activeLetter: this.state.activeLetter + 1,
        });
            console.log('check 1')
        if ( this.state.activeLetter === txt[this.state.activeText].length ) {

            console.log('check 2')
            this.setState({
                activeText: this.state.activeText + 1,
            })
            if ( this.state.activeText === txt.length ) return; 


                return setTimeout(() => {
                    this.setState({
                        activeLetter: 0,
                        text: '',
                    })
                }, 2000)
        }
        setTimeout(this.idInterval, 100);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div onLoad={this.idInterval}>
                    <p>{this.state.text}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

// const indexTyping = setInterval(addLetter, 50);

export default AnimationTypingText;
```

````
1 of 4030 errors on the page
TypeError: Cannot read property '49' of undefined
AnimationTypingText.addLetter
src/components/AnimationTypingText.js:25
  22 | 
  23 | if ( this.state.activeLetter >= 0 ) {
  24 |     this.setState({
> 25 |         text: this.state.text + txt[this.state.activeText][this.state.activeLetter],
     | ^  26 |     });
  27 | }
  28 | this.setState({
View compiled
(anonymous function)
src/components/AnimationTypingText.js:3
  1 | import React, { Component } from 'react';
  2 | 
> 3 | class AnimationTypingText extends Component {
  4 |     state = {
  5 |         text: '',
  6 |         indexText: 0,```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem!

My advice is to write a function to know if there is a future character in the line and another to get the future line to display (and return to line 0 if we were on the last).

Also, be aware of the [asynchronous nature](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) of `setState`. If the state you currently build is dependant of the precedent state, you need to use the syntax :

```
setState(previousState => { ... })
```

You can try [my solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-pascal-plspk) :

```
import React from "react";

class AnimationTypingText extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: "",
    indexText: 0,
    activeLetter: -1,
    activeText: 0
  };

  idInterval = setInterval(() => this.addLetter(), 50);

  addLetter = () => {
    const txt = [
      "HTML Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur",
      "CSS adipisicing elit. Repellat, laudantium dolorum",
      "JavaScript consequuntur dicta esse soluta aut assumenda",
      "React error iusto qui atque necessitatibus ",
      "Node tempore dolor laborum.",
      "MongoDB Aspernatur quam voluptatum quis possimus."
    ];

    const getNextLine = () => {
      if (this.state.activeText >= txt.length - 1) {
        return 0;
      } else return this.state.activeText + 1;
    };

    const hasNextChar = () => {
      if (this.state.activeLetter < txt[this.state.activeText].length - 1) {
        return true;
      } else return false;
    };

    if (hasNextChar()) {
      this.setState(previousState => ({
        text:
          previousState.text +
          txt[previousState.activeText][previousState.activeLetter + 1],
        activeLetter: previousState.activeLetter + 1
      }));
    } else {
      const nextLine = getNextLine();

      this.setState({
        activeText: nextLine,
        text: "",
        activeLetter: -1
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.text}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AnimationTypingText;
```

One last thing, if you don't want to run forever like my solution, be careful to clear the interval in a [`componentWillUnmount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) method.

Comment: Yes.
 Your answer is really helpful. I don't have that much of practical experience with React, and you gave me a lot of ideas what to look for. 
 I'll try with that for now and try to adjust. Works almost as I wanted. Just need to figure it out, how to make setTimeout for little brake between changing texts.
 I want to vote it up, but I need few more reputation points to do that. I will do it , after reaching 15 points. 
Thank you very much. :)